# Xamarin form: Push Notification using FCM

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I am looking at the documentation to setup push notification for android.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push#create-hub

```
await AzureNotificationHubService.RegisterAsync(TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.GetPush(), token);
```

The CurrentClient is a MobileServiceClient which have GetPush function.

When I look at nugget, I saw the a package called "WindowsAzure.MobileServices" but it was deprecated. I am unsure is this the right package the document is using. If it is, it was deprecated. Which alternative package to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WindowsAzure.MobileServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/) is used as the client SDK for Azure mobile Services. The [Add push notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push) tutorial you mentioned is talking about Azure Mobile Apps, you need to use this SDK [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client) in your Xamarin application.

Additionally, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop-migration-from-mobile-services) about the comparison between Mobile Services and Mobile Apps.

---

**UPDATE:**

The tutorial [Get started with Azure Notification Hubs for Xamarin.iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started#connect-your-app-to-the-notification-hub) is talking about directly accessing Azure Notification Hubs in your Xamarin application via the related notification Hubs client SDK.

While for Azure Mobile Apps, you configure the notification hub under the "Settings > Push" of your mobile app, then your Xamarin application directly accessing your mobile app backend, `TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.GetPush()` would internally accessing the build-in endpoints provided under your mobile app backend. Moreover, you could check the related `GetPush` method under [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/11c9bcd3c1e16a32cff27460ef836888cbd2d9fa/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/Platforms/uwp/Extensions/MobileServiceClientExtensions.cs) for UWP platform, and the [Push.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/8f0fc245f29c5b3245ce27e8428b0f4a90b948bc/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/Platforms/uwp/Push/Push.cs) would use [PushHttpClient.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/8f0fc245f29c5b3245ce27e8428b0f4a90b948bc/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/Push/PushHttpClient.cs) for registration management.

Comment: Coz I am using the WindowsAzure.Messaging at the moment. Is this part of the Azure Mobile Services, in nugget doesn't say deprecated..

Comment: There's no relationship between them.

Comment: I am abit confusing with Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client with the link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started

Comment: I just updated my answer for your confused part, you could refer to the updated part.